# How to annotate the type of a function within an object?

Tags: typescript

What is the proper way to type this object?

```
{a: 1, b: n => n + 1}
```

Here's my [attempt](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKANgpgLgBAZgewQLhgbwIaoHYFcC2ARhAE4A0MhOBxJMAvAHwx5GkC%20D6WMAjBVRYNm2GAGo%207UEA).

```
let foo: {a: number, b: number => number} = {a: 1, b: n => n + 1}
```

However, this isn't the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function type expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) need parentheses and parameter names. From the handbook:

> Note that the **parameter name is required**. The function type `(string) => void` means “a function with a parameter named string of type any“!

```
let foo: {a: number, b: (n: number) => number} = {a: 1, b: n => n + 1}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=71&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKANgpgLgBAZgewQLhgbwIaoHYFcC2ARhAE4A0MhqAFNjgcSQJQwC8AfDHkaQL5vosMAIwUqXNp2wwA1CN6ggA)

Answer (score 3):

[Function syntax documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html)

```
let foo: {a: number, b: (n: number) => number} = {a: 1, b: n => n + 1}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=71&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDeBDRA7ArgWwEYgCcAaCXRACnQx3wIEoIBeAPgiz0IF8nk0IBGEmTZNW6CAGoBnIA)